Adding more pins to a symbol in Altium Designer
I've made a custom symbol in altium designer, and I want to add more pins to it. I have already saved it and created it, and when I try edit it I can't seem to find any option to edit the amount of pins.
how could I do this ?

Editing placed parts (SCH or PCB) is between annoying, and impossible.
The most I would recommend is editing SCH pins (length, name/number, hide), or PCB pads (or other minor modifications or deletion of objects).  It is possible to add objects to a footprint (Tools/Convert/Add Selected Primitives to Footprint) but it's not very convenient.  I don't think there's an analogous process for SCH at all; at most, pins can be edited by selecting in Inspector (Properties), with query if needed (e.g. Pins Locked enabled) or selection if not, or by editing pins in the pin editor dialog.
It is, at least, simple enough to edit parts in the library editor:

Create a new SCH/PCB library
Copy and paste the part from the sheet/board into the library
Edit it freely as needed
Place in the design
Save the library to disk if you want a more permanent record, expect to go back and edit it later, etc.

It's not a bad idea to have a library associated with the project to handle anything customized for it, assuming of you aren't using a more formalized process (like database linked symbols) of course.
If you've already made the part in a library, just add the library to the project or workspace, and create variant copies of the part in it, or use another library to avoid cluttering the main one, etc..
